# Evaluate a limit involving inderterminate terms

Tags: limits

Find the limit $$\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{e^{(x^x-1)}-x^x}{((x^2)^x-1)^2}$$

The options are provided as 
(a) 1   (b)$\frac{1}{8}$ (c) -1  (d) Does not exist

Please suggest how should I use the standard limits or any other theorem on limits to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change $t=x^x$ first.

Answer (score 1):

The denominator can be written as $(x^x-1)^{2}(x^{x}+1)^{2}$ and the second factor tends to $4$. Next put $t=x\log x$  so that the limit becomes $$\frac{1}{4}\lim_{t\to 0}e^{t}\cdot\frac{\exp(e^{t}-1-t)-1}{(e^{t}-1)^{2}} =\frac{1}{4}\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\exp(e^{t}-1-t)-1}{e^{t}-1-t}\cdot\frac{e^{t}-1-t}{t^{2}}\cdot\left(\frac{t}{e^{t}-1}\right)^{2}$$ and the limit is thus $(1/4)\cdot 1\cdot(1/2)\cdot 1=1/8$.

You will need to use L'Hospital's Rule or Taylor series expansions to get the following limit $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^{t}-1-t}{t^{2}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively: making the change $t=x^x$:
$$\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{e^{(x^x-1)}-x^x}{((x^2)^x-1)^2}=\lim_{t\to1}\frac{e^{(t-1)}-t}{(t-1)^2(t+1)^2}=$$
$$\frac14\lim_{t\to1}\frac{e^{(t-1)}-t}{(t-1)^2}\stackrel{LR}{=}\frac14\lim_{t\to1}\frac{e^{(t-1)}-1}{2(t-1)}=\frac18.$$

Comment: Can you pls. help me understand how did ${x\to0+}$ change into ${t\to1}$